# How to install the leopard OS?

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, imac

I have an apple laptop.But the OS is corrupted.I have a new one to use the apple laptop.But i have an licensed version.

## What I need:

How to install the leopard os....
What are the steps am i should follow...

Comment: You have tagged the question as Macbook Pro **and** iMac which OS do you have and what specific Apple Laptop?

Comment: since adalarasan hasn't clarified the question at all, I think this should be closed

Answer (score 7):

After backing up your system, insert your shiny OS X DVD into your Mac and restart the computer, holding down C, so that the Mac boots off of the DVD-ROM.

After a few moments, you will be presented with a installation screen and presented with a number of options.

Answer (score 2):

What Apple laptop you have?

You can simple slide your CD and start the instllation program and it will check for compatibility and if your Laptop is compatible it will upgrade it.